# How to pass JSON data to another screen in flutter from a gridview

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Hello i have 2 screens in flutter the 1st page contains many JSON data like image,strings, etc to be pass in 2nd page how to to this? Thank in advance.

I have the my code below i stuck here for almost 4 hours now Can anybody help me.

```
 //first page
 Map data;
 List userData;

  Future getItems() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get("MY_IP/olstore_serv/get_items");
  data = json.decode(response.body);
  setState(() {
    userData  = data["item"];
  });

  onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
        new CupertinoPageRoute(
             builder: (context) {
                return new ItemDetails(todo:userData);
              },
            ),
          );
       },


/// second page
 class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {
   final List todo;


  ItemDetails({this.todo});
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('i want to display item name here pls help me'),
      ),
     child: Container(
       child: ListView(
           physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
           children: <Widget>[
            Text('here too'),
          ]
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: userData is a List. So what do you want to display from the list as the text ?

Comment: i want to get item name from a json and display it in a Text() widget in the ItemDetails page

Comment: please put the json

Comment: i already put the json in my navigator push

Comment: i mean show us the content in your json

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for listview.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: todo.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Text(todo[index].yourKey);
      },
    );
```

Comment: what is yourkey ?

Comment: yourkey means your json key for getting text.

Comment: can you give a whole sample?